# Rerendering a component everytime in react native or calling a function on screen showing

Tags: react-native

I want to implement logout feature in my app and my logout menu is appearing using a drawer navigation menu.When I am clicking the logout menu for the first time my code written in the logout component useeffect hook is running and redirecting to the login page but from the second time it is not working as the useeffect function is not called.How to run that function everytiem when my logout screen appear on the screen.My logout component code is like this.

```
import React,{ useState,useEffect,useCallback } from "react";
import { View,StyleSheet,ActivityIndicator,AsyncStorage} from "react-native";
import GenericAPICall from "../WebUtils/GenericAPICall";


const Logout=({navigation})=>{

    const[isVisible,setVisible]=useState(true);

removeSession=()=>{
    console.log('session');
    var magToken=AsyncStorage.getItem('magtoken');
    AsyncStorage.removeItem('magtoken');
    AsyncStorage.setItem('isloggedin', "false");
    navigation.navigate("Login");
    setVisible(false);
}

    useEffect(() => removeSession(),[]);

        return(

        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ActivityIndicator animating={isVisible} size="large" color="#0000ff" />
        </View>
)
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center'
    }
  })

export default Logout;
```

Answer (score 1):

firstly, the AsyncStore is async function, you should modify `removeSession` function.

```
removeSession= async ()=>{
    console.log('session');
    if(isVisible){
      navigation.navigate("Login");
    }
    // it is uselesss
    // var magToken= await AsyncStorage.getItem('magtoken');
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem('magtoken');
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('isloggedin', "false");
    setVisible(false);
}
```

Secondly, if you use the navigation to enter the logout screen. the second time, it is not re-mount. you can change to use the navigation lifecycle method. then you may need to change it to component or use [`react-native-hooks](https://github.com/react-navigation/hooks#usefocusstate)

```
useFocusEffect(useCallback(() => {
    console.debug("screen takes focus");
    removeSession()
    return () => console.debug("screen loses focus");
  }, []));
```